# Agora voice(Group) call - How to get active members/ joining callbacks?

Tags: java, android, voice, agora.io

I'm currently using the Agora group voice call demo project.
When a user joins the call, I'm not receiving any callbacks.
How to get active users?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to make a call, please check if you are using the correct appid and token. Here is the article for more information: https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/token.

To test your Agora Appid and token, you can use the Agora web showcase demo: https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1-Web/. You can enter your Appid and token in two web showcase demos and see if you can make a call between them.

If you are able to make a call, when a user join and you can see his remote video, you should be able to see one of this callback been triggered based on which is implemented in the demo app: onUserJoined, onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded, onRemoteVideoStateChanged.